# Sip Application with pjsip crashes on certain android devices

Tags: android, pjsua2

I tried testing my pjsip app with 10 devices. Out of which app crashed with certain devices. Below is the list of those android devices.

**SUCCESSFULL**

---

1. SAMSUNG J5 (ARMV7)
2. SM-J2 60G   (ARMV7)
3. REDMI NOTE 5  (AARMV8-A)
4. IBRIT SPEEDX  (ARMV7)
5. REALME C2 (AARCH64)
6. VIVO Y90 (AARCH64)

**FAILED**

---

1. Asus Z010D (aarch 64)
2. Gionee G7a (aarch 64)
3. Oppo A37f (Lollipop - AArch64 - arm64-v8a instruction set)

I took pjsua build for architecture armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a.

I came to know that these failed devices fall under AArch64 architecture. How can i take a build for AArch64? Why App crashes on these devices without showing any error logs?

Comment: `Why App crashes` it usually says in stacktrace, crash logs, etc.

Comment: `arm64-v8a` supports `aarch 64` So you have already build for AArch64  refer this link https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#sa

Comment: @TakeInfos - Yeah that is what I also understood.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko  - In Gionee G7a , I got an error like this :

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "freeifaddrs" referenced by "/data/app/com.xtendsip-2/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so"...

Comment: at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
at com.xtendsip.MyApp.<clinit>(MyApp.java:359)
at com.xtendsip.MainService.onCreate(MainService.java:100)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3078)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1582)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching, I found out that the issue is with my ndk. I am using latest version of ndk which is r20. afaik, r20 does not support android versions below 7. So, I want to minimise my android NDK version to something 15 or below for my app to run on android devices below 7.